# HOw to Display the multirow variable set or variable set in a table in service catalogue item?

Tags: widget, servicenow, servicenow-client-scripts

I'm trying to display the fields of the form in a table. Now this form has variables, variable sets, multirow variables, I want to show these in a table & export as PDF. Is there any way to achieve this functionality.

I did not find anyway to display all the data in a table, please let me know if there is a way.